# Mongoose Update *ONE* Field if Found Otherwise Create New With All Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a schema with multiple fields. I want to update only *ONE* field if a document matches my query. However, if not, I want to create a new document with values for all fields. Is there a way to use `Model.findOneAndUpdate` for this?

Here is code for more concreteness and what I have tried:

```
var mg = require('mongoose');   
var Record = mg.model ("record", {
  field1: Number,
  field2: Number,
  field3: Number,
});

//Update field1 ONLY if found using findOneAndUpdate, else create with all fields
var query = {//My Query},
    update = {field1: 10},
    options = {upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true};

Record.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err,result){
  //Do stuff with doc
});
```

The above code updates `field1` correctly, but when no document matches the query, a new document is created without `field2` or `field3`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I read the documentation on [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior) and realized that what I needed was to include update operators in my `update` object and use `$setOnInsert`. As the name implies, the value that is associated with this operator will only be set if a new document is being inserted. So fixed code from question

```
var mg = require('mongoose');   
var Record = mg.model ("record", {
  field1: Number,
  field2: Number,
  field3: Number,
});

//Update field1 ONLY if found using findOneAndUpdate, else create with all fields
var query = {//My Query},
    update = {
      $set:{field1: 10},
      $setOnInsert:{field2: ..., field3: ...}
    },
    options = {upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true};

Record.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err,result){
  //Do stuff with doc
});
```